# Which type sizes can I use for specific semantics

Tags: semantics, hlsl

Microsoft provides a [list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509647(v=vs.85).aspx) explaining the input and output semantics of vertex and pixel shaders. By now I've seen some code examples that don't use the documented data types. They are using `float3` as input `COLOR` to the pixel shader or `float2` as input `POSITION` to the vertex shader. Even though a 2-component position or a 3-component color do make sense to me, I can't find this documented, which makes me wonder

- Can I use `float3` as vertex shader input `POSITION` (if I know I won't be using the W component) without expecting errors?
- If I can use data types other than the documented ones, is there a list available that shows every allowed data type for a semantic or a rule like "As long as the used data type is smaller or equally sized as the documented one, you can use it"?

---

Code examples not following the documentation:

[StackOverflow - Passing colors through a pixel shader in HLSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760920)

[C++ / DirectX11 Tutorials - S02E05 - Creating and loading Shaders](https://youtu.be/6_cNvTTFVSQ?t=9m33s) at 9:33

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In shader model 4.0 and later (DX10+), the only semantic names that matter are system-value semantics (those prefixed by `SV_`). Other semantics have no special treatment aside from being used to match shader parameters to their inputs. The documentation regarding semantics such as `COLOR` being `float4` is purely convention, or legacy from DX9. In DX10/SM4+, there's nothing stopping you from declaring `COLOR` as a `float2`, or deciding to use `UNICORN` as the semantic name for your colors, though don't be surprised if this confuses other developers (or yourself) reviewing the code in the future.

To answer your specific question, **yes** you can use any data type you want for non-`SV_` semantics, or even invent your own names. Just make sure you use consistent naming and channel counts between stages and input layout declaration.

Comment: Ahh, that's great! After thinking about it, this kinda makes sense. Because the shader's input structure and the vertex structure in code are equally structured, DirectX just copies the raw structure over to the GPU and thus doesn't need to know the specific component sizes. Thank you :)